# Correctly naming variables types

Tags: python, list, tuples

For a project I have to use lists, tuples or even list of tuples (array of vertices for example) and so on.
While writing methods, classes I want to specify the type of their variables. For example:

```
def Example_Method(self, name: str, age: int):
    return name + str(age)
```

or

```
class Example_Class:
    def __init__(self, cents: int):
        self.euros: float = cents / 100
```

With basic types it is all nice and clean, but how does one name list of floats, tuple of strings or even list of lists or list of tuples.
Have searched for information, but couldn't find any or don't know how to name it correctly.

Comment: what do you mean by "name it"?

Comment: "Have searched for information" So, when you specifically put something like `python specify type` into a search engine and got something like [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) as the first result, as I did, and saw examples right near the top that look like `list[float]` and `dict[str, str]` and `tuple[str, int]`, what exactly did you find confusing or insufficient about the information there?

Comment: @deadshot  I meant name variable's type for a better readability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all this, there is the excellent `typing` [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

In your case you could to

```
from typing import List, Tuple
```

and then you can type hint a variable by doing, for example,

```
age: List[float] = [28.2, 78.9, 40.5]
names: Tuple[str, str, str] = ('Simon', 'Alice', 'Bob')
```

and so on. The library is extremely flexible. For a dictionary, for example, it lets you specify the type of keys and values separately as well. If you read the documentation it will show you how to type hint even very complex stuff. It's worth noting that as of Python 3.9, most of the functionalities of this library have been incorporated into the python syntax. So unless you need the `typing` library for complex cases (e.g. you need to type hint a `Callable`, i.e. a function, or you need to specify multiple possible types using `Union` etc.) you can just type hint things in python, so the examples above would become:

```
age: list[float] = [28.2, 78.9, 40.5]
names: tuple[str, str, str] = ('Simon', 'Alice', 'Bob')
```

without you needing to import any library. You still need the `typing` library for Python 3.8 and below.

Comment: Thank you, the library works perfect. I am using python to program an executable script for Blender (3D modeling program). Might be that the second example (without library) is not working specifically on Blender's editor.

Comment: You'd need to check which version of python your script is running on.
Also, note I made a slight error in my earlier answer. Tuples support type hinting for each of their element, so a tuple with 3 elements can have 3 separate inner hints, as opposed to lists. If you want to specify a tuple with an unspecified number of elements of one type, e.g. a tuple of strings, you can use the ellipsis notation with ..., i.e.
`Tuple[str, ...]`